# How to remove standard field mappings when synchronizing data between AD and user profiles?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, active-directory, profile-sync

It is necessary to prevent overwriting the values of FirstName, LastName, PreferredName fields during synchronization user profiles with AD. How can I do that?

Comment: what SharePoint version you are using and which Profile Sync method? also you dont want overwrite the Values in AD, right?

Comment: To add to that, regardless of method, those values are not exported from SharePoint to AD by default. In fact, no field is exported from SharePoint to AD by default.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP I am using SP2016. And yes, modification of data in AD is not allowed.

Comment: @TrevorSeward https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510

Comment: What's the link for. Again, by default, nothing is exported from SharePoint to AD. As you have to configure explicit permissions in Active Directory for the sync account, there's no reason to make export part of any default setup.